# Changing query in resource filter breaks model binding

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a case where I'm receiving `"null"` as one of query parameters. Since my model expects a `DateTime?`, execution fails at the model binding.

I thought of implementing a filter that will remove invalid `"null"` values. Here's how I implemented it:

```cs
public class NullWorkaroundFilterAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context) { }

    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Query["myDate"] != "null")
        {
            return;
        }

        var queryParams = context.HttpContext.Request.Query
            .Select(n => (n.Key, Value: n.Value == "null" ? "" : n.Value.ToString()))
            .ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => new StringValues(n.Value));
        
        context.HttpContext.Request.Query = new QueryCollection(queryParams);
    }
}
```

When I debug, it seems that the newly created `QueryCollection` contains the right values. However, it turns out that my action receives a model where all the values are default! All `string?` parameters become `null`, while all the `DateTime`s become `0001/01/01` Even though all the parameters are now correct, somehow the fact that I'm replacing the Query object breaks model binding.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Could you please share how this `Request.Query["myDate"]` value has been passed?

Comment: It was http://localhost:5000?myDate=null